# Including template functions in ROOT's CINT

Tags: c++, interpreter, root-framework

To make available some useful function in CINT (C++ interpreter of ROOT), I configured my `rootrc` config file to execute a `rootlogon.C` file each time I run `root` to launch the interpreter.

In `rootlogon.C`, this piece of code is present:

```cpp
{
  gROOT->ProcessLine("#include \"GenericToolbox.h\"");
}
```

This line is kind of working as intented since I'm then able to access most of the defined function in the header file. However the functions involving template can't be accessed. I understand that because this is a header-only library, the interpreter can't predict which object types will be used as template definition.

**So do you know if I could make a kind of shared library that could be loaded in the rootlogon, which would define specific template functions?**

I've seen some examples suggesting to utilize a `LinkDef.h` file which contains `#pragma link C++ function` lines to specialize templates, but I don't understand how to use it...

Any idea?

Comment: Which version of root are you using? (specifically wondering about root 5 vs root 6)

I just created a header with a templated function, include it from rootlogon like you did and I can call the function just fine without any pragmas or linkdefs.

Comment: I'm using ROOT 6. What you said is surprizing..! How did you include the header ?

Comment: what i have in production are lines like these: https://github.com/pseyfert/dotfiles/blob/6e7ec36823fba656e9350f0bc9508a8b37a06eef/rootlogon.C#L18 . so basically `gROOT->ProcessLine("#include ...");`. in the linked example i do the function definition directly in the logon file through `gROOT->ProcessLine("template <typename T> ...");`. but i also tried putting `#include <...> template <typename T> auto ...` into a `myheader.h` and in rootlogon do `gROOT->ProcessLine("myheader.h");`